# MySQL to Azure SQL through CSV file

Tags: c#, mysql, csv, azure-sql-database

If I export a MySQL table into a .csv file, is there any extra work needed to now push this .csv file onto an Azure SQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any extra work needed to now push this .csv file onto an Azure SQL database?

For flat CSV file, you could create the destination table in your Azure SQL Database first, then use the bcp command-line utility for importing data from a CSV file into your Azure SQL Database. For more details, you could refer to [Load data from CSV into Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-load-from-csv-with-bcp#before-you-begin).

Additionally, you could migrate your MySQL database objects to SQL Azure, then migrate the data to SQL Azure. For more details, you could refer to the following tutorials:

[Migrating MySQL Databases to SQL Server - Azure SQL DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/migrating-mysql-databases-to-sql-server-azure-sql-db-mysqltosql)

[Migrating MySQL Data into SQL Server - Azure SQL DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/migrating-mysql-data-into-sql-server-azure-sql-db-mysqltosql)

Comment: Thanks Bruce, this is a great answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also and upload results into blob storage and use natively built in BCP in Azure SQL to pull the data.

Here is example on how to do it https://marczak.io/posts/azure-loading-csv-to-sql/

Alternatively you can easily load data from blob storage into database using Azure data Factory, you can example find here: https://azure4everyone.com/posts/2019/07/data-factory-intro/